# firebase filter query not working (where in)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on where in query in react but not getting filtered data.

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState(null);
  const uid1 = 30;
  const uid2 = 31;
  useEffect(() => {
    // show chat messages
    db.collection("chat").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      setMessage(
        snapshot.docs.map((item) => ({
          uid1: item.data().uid1,
          uid2: item.data().uid2,
          message: item.data().message,
          id: item.id,
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("chat")
      .where("uid1", "in", [uid1, uid2])
      .orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          if (
            (doc.data().uid1 == uid1 && doc.data().uid2 == uid2) ||
            (doc.data().uid1 == uid2 && doc.data().uid2 == uid1)
          ) {
            setConversations(doc.data());
          }
        });
      });
  }, []);
  console.log({ conversations });
```

for reference, this is my firebase data.
[image: firebase]

also this is my index rules

[image: index]

Comment: What are the values of the `uid1` and `uid2` variables in the code you shared? Can you reproduce the problem when you use hard-coded values instead of those variables? If so, please edit your question (there's a link right under it for this purpose) to show the problem with hard-coded values, instead of variables that we can't see the value of.

Comment: as mentioned in edit , it is uid1 = 30 and uid2 = 31

Comment: So you say that inside `.where("uid1", "in", [uid1, uid2])` the values are 30 and 31, right?

Comment: Running into this same exact issue. @TejendraSinghRajawat, did you ever figure this out? My only difference is that I am using `.get()` on the query instead of `onSnapshot()`, but the result is the same; records that I can see exist are not returned.